# how to access localhost url from other PC's on windows 10?

Tags: mysql, url, xampp, windows-10

I have developed a website using netbeans 8.2, Xampp MySQL, tomcat 8. Now I want to access it from other systems or PC's. My localhost url can be accessed from my PC only. I tried by changing hosts file on local computer C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts but hosts file is only accessible for my PC, not for other PC's. I am using this website for internal netwrok only and my IP address is static. I tried to add this line into my hosts file.

```html
10.226.43.47 dms.zf.com
```

Comment: someone please help me for above problem

Comment: you need to use a domain name server for this. Where dd you buy your domain from ? they should already be providing you a DNS

Comment: @SudiptaMondal how to use domain name server to do this?